# Variant of `some-fn` for multiple arguments

Tags: clojure

I find myself in need a function that is similar to `some-fn` but combines predicates that take multiple arguments.

The new function should take a set of predicates and return a function `f`. The function `f` should return the first logical true value returned by one of its composing predicates **applied to all of `f`'s arguments**, or else logical false. So I should be able to do this:

```
((some-fn* < >) 1 2)
=> truthy

((some-fn* < >) 1 1)
=> falsey
```

It's easy enough to implement:

```
(defn some-fn* [& fs]
  (fn [& args] (loop [fs fs]
                 (when (seq fs)
                   (or (apply (first fs) args)
                       (recur (rest fs)))))))
```

But it seems like such a simple thing should already exist in clojure.core. Does it? Or is there a simpler way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `some`:

```
(defn some-fn* [& ps]
  (fn [& args]
    (some #(apply % args) ps)))
```